# std::get from teplate argument

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

Could you please explane or maybe give a link that explains:
why this works:

```
template <int i, int j, class T>
auto to_pair(T tuple) -> decltype(std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple), std::get<j>(tuple)))
{
    return std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple), std::get<j>(tuple));
}
```

and this does not?

```
template <class T>
auto to_pair(int i, int j, T tuple) -> decltype(std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple), std::get<j>(tuple)))
{
    return std::make_pair(std::get<i>(tuple), std::get<j>(tuple));
}
```

I mean what is the difference between int type being template argument specialization and int argument as a common argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I mean what is the difference between int type being template argument specialization and int argument as a common argument?

One is defined at compile time while the other is defined at run time.

A run time value cannot be used as a template parameter. Hence, the second case does not work.

Comment: but why the second case is known at run-time?
I mean to_pair is going to be compiled with i,j variables, so their types are known?

Comment: The types are known but not their values. When you use `std::get<i>(tuple)`, the value of `i` must be known at compile time.